# How can I find distance between two lines (linestrings from geojson) on earth

Tags: go, geometry, line, distance, geojson

How can I find the smallest distance between two lines on Earth if I have their latitudes and longitudes? 
Preference to golang, but it'll be cool in an any programming language

I really tried to find it, but I can only find how to do it for two points

Comment: Please show us some code of what you have tried. SO is not a code writing service.

Comment: I don't even know which formula to use for line-line distance. I have code for line-point distance only
Can you give me a hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get points http://turfjs.org/docs#explode and via http://turfjs.org/docs#coordEach find its distance to line http://turfjs.org/docs#pointToLineDistance

Comment: Thanks, I understand what you mean... I thought that there's a special formula for this

Comment: There are formulas... I've seen them somewhere.. But this geo library is brilliant. It will save you live will all kind of geo related functions.

Answer (score 0):

So, I do this
I have two lines AB and CD
I find distance from point A to line CD, from point C to CD, from point C to line AB, from point D to line AB
Put it all into array and after than find the smallest distance

(if line lines do not intersect or parallel, i'll put this cases into special condition)

Comment: Correct. Either simple way http://turfjs.org/docs/#distance or more math kind of https://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html will help you

Comment: I used  movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html for point to point measurements. Than you for all links you gave, you helped me with your clue :)